# How to show both month view and week view in the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fullcalendar

I want to show both month view and week view in the same time in Full calendar in react. Can anyone help me? This is my code

```
                   <FullCalendar
                      firstDay={1}
                      header={{
                        left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,listWeek'
                      }}
                      views={{
                        listWeek: { buttonText: "Week" },
                        month: { buttonText: "Month" }
                      }}
                      timeFormat='H:mm'
                      plugins={['interaction']}
                      selectable={true}
                      fixedWeekCount={false}
                      defaultDate={this.props.choosenDate ? this.props.choosenDate : moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
                      defaultView={this.state.calendarView}
                      navLinks={true} // can click day/week names to navigate views
                      navLinkDayClick={this.dayClick}
                      editable={false}
                      eventLimit={2} // allow "more" link when too many events
                      events={aclCheck("EventView") && this.props.events && this.props.events.rows ? this.state.events : []}
                      showNonCurrentDates={false}
                      select={(info, info1) => {
                        this.selectedDate = { start: info, end: info1 }
                      }}
                    />
```

This is the month view and week view. Thanks in advance

[image: Month view]

[image: Week view]

Comment: for that you will need to create two separate calendar instances

Comment: @ADyson I tried that for one I gave

defaultView="listWeek"

and other I gave 

defaultView="month"

If I give defaultView same that is month for both it works but if  I give if differently as above it is notworking

Comment: The calendars would be independent of each other, so that shouldn't be a problem. Perhaps you didn't configure it quite right.

Comment: @ADyson I got it right when I added the other fullCalendar in another account